# How do I fix my chart data being displayed when using HealthKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, healthkit

I am having issues with my chart data when reading the data from HealthKit. I'm using a long running query with an update handler to add new data/values in the background. However, my chart data seems to be redrawing whenever I close and open the app which makes the line go crazy. My list below also gets additional repeated values. I tried fixing this issue by stopping the query using a .onDisappear modifier but the .onDisappear wouldn't update the values unless I force closed the app and opened it again.

```
//Properties within my view model for resting HR.
var restingHRquery: HKStatisticsCollectionQuery?
@Published var restingHR: [RestingHeartRate] = [RestingHeartRate]()


    func calculateRestingHRData() {
        
        let restingHRpredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: oneWeekAgo, end: nil, options: .strictStartDate)
        
        
        restingHRquery =   HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: restingHeartRateType,
                                                       quantitySamplePredicate: restingHRpredicate,
                                                       options: .discreteAverage,
                                                       anchorDate: anchorDate,
                                                       intervalComponents: daily)
        
        
        restingHRquery!.initialResultsHandler = {
            restingQuery, statisticsCollection, error in
            
            //Handle errors here
            if let error = error as? HKError {
                switch (error.code) {
                case .errorHealthDataUnavailable:
                    return
                case .errorNoData:
                    return
                default:
                    return
                }
            }
            
            guard let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection else { return}
            
            //Calculating resting HR
            statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: self.startDate, to: self.date) { statistics, stop in
                if let restHRquantity = statistics.averageQuantity() {
                    let hrdate = statistics.startDate
                    
                    //HR Units
                    let hrUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
                    let restHRvalue = restHRquantity.doubleValue(for: hrUnit)
                    let restHR = RestingHeartRate(restingValue: Int(restHRvalue), date: hrdate)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.restingHR.append(restHR)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        restingHRquery!.statisticsUpdateHandler = {
            restingQuery, statistics, statisticsCollection, error in
            
            //Handle errors here
            if let error = error as? HKError {
                switch (error.code) {
                case .errorHealthDataUnavailable:
                    return
                case .errorNoData:
                    return
                default:
                    return
                }
            }
            
            guard let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection else { return}
            
            //Calculating resting HR
            statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: self.startDate, to: self.date) { statistics, stop in
                if let restHRquantity = statistics.averageQuantity() {
                    let hrdate = statistics.startDate
                    
                    //HR Units
                    let hrUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
                    let restHRvalue = restHRquantity.doubleValue(for: hrUnit)
                    let restHR = RestingHeartRate(restingValue: Int(restHRvalue), date: hrdate)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.restingHR.append(restHR)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        guard let restingHRquery = self.restingHRquery else { return }
      
        self.healthStore?.execute(restingHRquery)
    }
```

```
struct OneWeekRestHRChartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var healthStoreVM: HealthStoreViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
      
            Text("Average: \(healthStoreVM.averageRestHR) bpm")
                .font(.headline)
            
            Chart {
                ForEach(healthStoreVM.restingHR.reversed(), id: \.date) {
                    restHrData in
                    
                    LineMark(x: .value("day", restHrData.date, unit: .day),
                             y: .value("RHR", restHrData.restingValue)
                    )
                    .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
                    .symbol() {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.red)
                            .frame(width: 15)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            .chartYScale(domain: 30...80)
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .day)) {
                    AxisGridLine()
                    AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.day().month(), centered: true)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .navigationTitle("Resting Heart Rate")

        
        List{
            ForEach(healthStoreVM.restingHR.reversed(), id: \.date) {
                restHR in
                
                DataListView(imageText: "heart.fill",
                             imageColor: .red,
                             valueText: "\(restHR.restingValue) bpm",
                             date: restHR.date)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.inset)
    }
}
```

Could this just be a SwiftUI chart issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `statisticsUpdateHandler` is not called with only the new results.  It is called with an updated complete set of results.

You need to clear your existing results from `restingHR` before you add the results again.

```
restingHRquery!.statisticsUpdateHandler = {
            restingQuery, statistics, statisticsCollection, error in
            
            //Handle errors here
            if let error = error as? HKError {
                switch (error.code) {
                case .errorHealthDataUnavailable:
                    return
                case .errorNoData:
                    return
                default:
                    return
                }
            }
            
            guard let statisticsCollection = statisticsCollection else { return}

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.restingHR.removeAll()
            
            //Calculating resting HR
                statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: self.startDate, to: self.date) { statistics, stop in
                    if let restHRquantity = statistics.averageQuantity() {
                        let hrdate = statistics.startDate
                    
                        //HR Units
                        let hrUnit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
                        let restHRvalue = restHRquantity.doubleValue(for: hrUnit)
                        let restHR = RestingHeartRate(restingValue: Int(restHRvalue), date: hrdate)
                    
                        self.restingHR.append(restHR)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll try that. How does the stop query work? Does it just stop after the update with the new results? I'm just curious how it then re-updates your app view then.

Comment: Your array is @Published, so when you update the array, the view updates.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm messing with HKActivitySummaryQuery with an updateHandler and appending it to an array. Then I have a list view over the past 7 days but when I exit the app and go back in, it'll append the most recent value again. I tried using the removeAll() that you suggested but it just deletes all the data.

Comment: Data in an array won't be held when you restart your app. You need to fetch all if the data again or store it somewhere like a core data store, but it is probably best just to fetch the data from HealthKit when you need it